# Change default parameter for built-in class method

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm using `lxml` in my project. I have an input xml and need to parse it. The problem is that root element has `xmlns="some_url"`, for example

```
<root xmlns="some_url">
<child>some_text</child>
<child>some_text</child>
<child>
<sub_child>text</sub_child>
</child>
</root>
```

My xml is much more complex, so when I need to find some element, I use:

```
root.findall("nsp:child/nsp:sub_child", namespaces={"nsp":"some_url"})
```

So my code is full of `find` methods with the same `namespaces={"nsp":"some_url"}`
How can I pass this namespace once as default? I guess that I should inherit from `_SimpleElementPath` class. But how xml element will know to use this inherited class instead?

Answer (score 0):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think lxml has any concept of a default namespace unfortunately, you're always stuck passing the namespace explicitly. Perhaps write a custom decorator for the `findall()` method that passes your namespace?

Comment: how will it look like? Should I add this decorator to lxml `findall` method? But in this case, I change lib's code that is unacceptable